# BizTalk 2016 SFTP receive location

Tags: sftp, biztalk, biztalk-2016

We have a flow in BizTalk (currently 2010) where we read files from an SFTP location, but we don't have the permissions to delete files (it's a bank thing).
We have made a small customisation to the community SFTP adapter to check if we already received the file and skip it.

Is there a way to do the same thing with the standard BizTalk 2016 SFTP adapter? Or should I rebuild the community adapter to work in 2016?

Comment: Another case of how can we make this way unnecessarily complicated for everyone... ;)  Anyway, important question, does the directory contain only the current file and it's replaced periodically or does the directory keep growing indefinitely?

Comment: They always write a new file with a unique filename. All the old files remain in the same directory. I guess they have some kind of cleanup procedure, but we are not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

The SFTP Adapter in BizTalk Server does not support read-only endpoints.  Only the FTP/S Adapter does.

The best option is to license n/software's SFTP Adapter which does support read-only endpoints.

However, if you are comfortable with your modified community Adapter, that's is a valid option.

Comment: There are some issues with the community adapter. Mainly support for different SFTP servers. But it works for the endpoint I want to connect to. So for now I could live with my modified version. :-) Just trying to look for people with the same issue. Maybe it can be solved in a different way.